# Couchbase CLI/REST to get cluster current settings

Tags: couchbase

Im trying to find a way to monitor couchbase cluster settings such as memory, email configurations, etc.
Ideally it would be a cli/REST command that describes entire cluster configurations or its particular components.

Couchbase version: 4.5.1- Community Edition

Will appreciate for any advice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In current CB versions, you can get the email info using `http://hostname:8091/settings/alerts` and memory info using `http://hostname:8091/pools/nodes`

For some reason, I cannot seem to access the CB archived documentation to confirm this. Try it out and see if these APIs are available in 4.5.x. The pools API should be available. Not sure on the alerts API.

Comment: https://docs-archive.couchbase.com/server/4.5/rest-api/rest-endpoints-all.html